# LLPSI: Ch. 13, Ln. 120, 'Hōc annī tempore...'

Tags: syntax, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, ablative

My question stems from a passage of Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata Familia Romana in chapter 13 on page 99 beginning at line 120 as follows.

**Question**

What is the role of “Hōc annī tempore” in the sentence below and how if at all is it related to “aestāte”?

**Passage**

> “Hōc annī tempore diēs nōn tam calidī sunt quam aestāte et noctēs frīgidiōrēs sunt.”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hoc...tempore* is known as an [ablative of time](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/expressions-time):

> **Time when, or within which, is expressed by the ablative**...
>
> **cōnstitūtā diē**
> on the appointed day
>
> **prīmā lūce**
> at daybreak
>
> **quotā hōrā?**
> at what hour?
>
> **tertiā vigiliā**
> in the third watch

Etc.

So the translation here would be:

> At this time (*hoc tempore*) of year (*anni*).

It's simply letting you know the time during which the clause occurs.

By the way, if you come across an unusual accusative phrase that seems to sit apart from the sentence and refers to time, it's probably the accusative of time. You use the ablative when a specific point in time is referenced, and you use the accusative when you want to express duration through time.

Comment: My error with this sentence came from the thought that hōc was a pronoun before an antecedent without the notion that it could be a demonstrative adjective before tempore.